# How can I add special text format on GitHub?

Tags: github, text-formatting

I am trying to add text formatted in a special way to a GitHub repo on README.md file but it is not rendering the text format the way I want it.

I have attached images below. 
I want it to look like this:

[image: Desired Image]

BUT this is how it is rendering it:

[image: Actual Image]

So how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/

Put four spaces before each line.

Comment: Do you know how to select and add 4 spaces to a bunch of lines of texts? I need that too for formatting serverfault or all of stackexchange websites..its a pain selecting each line and doing it especially if the code is super long..thanks

Comment: @granttailor Programming text editors often offer multiple-line selection features.

Comment: but when am typing questions on stackexchange from my browser..am not sure how to use a texteditor to post questions from the browser...stackexchange obviously disbale this with their editor..have no idea why? other than knowingly make it more difficult to post questions +++ i use nano editor in Linux when working on git repos, so not sure how to do that either

Comment: @granttailor StackExchange doesn't disable it, it's just not built in to browser textareas. I just type longer posts into my text editor and copy them back when they're ready.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "StackExchange doesn't disable it, it's just not built in to browser textareas" i am sure you have used forum softwares(i.e vbulletin) before where you select a text and choose if it is quote or code...so not sure what you mean by SE did not disable it...more like they choose not to include and make it more difficult and annoying to post questions on their website..what arrogance.

Comment: @granttailor Uh, before you go claiming people are arrogant, you should probably check first. StackOverflow's editor has buttons for both blockquotes and code.

Comment: but when i click the buttons then it tells me to do it manually by following their instructions..right or wrong?

Comment: @granttailor Right or wrong, I'm done here. You couldn't be bothered to read the ServerFault "how to ask" section as you made this post, you're aggressively slamming StackExchange for missing features they have, and they don't owe you anything even if they didn't have the feature.

Comment: ok not sure what you saying..i am talking about the editor automatically make a group of selected lines as code or whatever NOT possible except manually doing it..and you defending SE..am not sure what you trying to do...if this can be done, then am sorry they may want to work on usability because if i haven't been able to figure that out for years then not sure what that is..i click the code button and it tells me to do it myself..what has this got to do with anything else?

Comment: @granttailor First, select the text you want to format as a code block (ie. indent by 4 spaces, fixed-width font, etc) _then_ click the "preformatted text" button `{}`. If you don't select the text first it just enters an example of inline-code markup, surrounded by backticks.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub flavored markdown supports [Using triple back ticks to fence code blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#fenced-code-blocks), which lets you wrap code blocks more easily than indenting every line.

> Standard Markdown converts text with four spaces at the beginning of each line into a code block; GFM also supports fenced blocks. Just wrap your code in ``` (as shown below) and you won't need to indent it by four spaces. Note that although fenced code blocks don't have to be preceded by a blank line—unlike indented code blocks—we recommend placing a blank line before them to make the raw Markdown easier to read.
>
> ````
> Here's an example:
>
> ```
> function test() {
>   console.log("notice the blank line before this function?");
> }
> ```
> ````
>
> Keep in mind that, within lists, you must indent non-fenced code blocks eight spaces to render them properly.